# Multiclass classification and imbalanced data

Tags: class-imbalance, multiclass-classification

My data has 20k instances of class A and 5 instances of class B. If I am using Cost Sensitive models (Cost-sensitive Logistic Regression, Cost-sensitive Decision Trees etc) for imbalanced datasets, do I then need to perform SMOTE and any other techniques?

Also some models are robust to imbalance like random forest, XGBoost. So if I am using these models, do I need to perform SMOTE?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This post is likely to get closed due to its uncertainty as the best practices are subjective. Therefore, if you really need this info, prepare a more specific question for the moment this question gets taken down. I had a similar case of my question being subjective but got lucky on getting the answer before it was nuked, so good luck!

Comment: @DmitriiBadretdinov Thanks for the heads up man:)

Comment: [It's not clear that class imbalance is a problem at all.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he)

Comment: @Dave I want to know if I am using Cost sensitive models or models that robust to imbalance, should I perform SMOTE or not.

Comment: The link I gave seems like an emphatic "no" to SMOTE. // If you only have five instances of the one class, your class imbalance issue is not the ratio of classes but the fact that you have almost no information about the one class.

Comment: @Dave So instead of SMOTE I should just go ahead with Cost Sensitive models or robust models like XGBoost or Random Forest?

Comment: I would suggest reading what Kolassa wrote and anything else you find on Cross Validated (or anywhere else) about proper scoring rules. Frank Harrell has two good blog posts. [1](https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/) [2](https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/)